# Proof Verification: Cartesian Product of Finitely Many Nonempty Sets is Nonempty (Without AoC)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

**Synopsis**

Please verify my proof. I would also appreciate any tips on how I might improve my mathematical writing. Thank you.

**Exercise**

Assume that $H$ is a function with finite domain $I$ and that $H(i)$ is nonempty for each $i \in I$. Without using the axiom of choice, show that there is a function $f$ with domain $I$ such that $f(i) \in H(i)$ for each $i \in I$. [*Suggestion:* Use induction on $\text{card }I$.]

**Proof**

Let $P(n)$ be the condition that $\text{card }I = n$ and that $H(i)$ is nonempty for each $i \in I$. Let $Q(n)$ be the condition that there exists a function $f$ with $\text{dom}f = I$ and with $f(i) \in H(i)$ for all $i \in I$. Consider the set $S = \{n \in \omega \mid P(n) \Rightarrow Q(n)\}$. We will show through induction that $S$ coincides with $\omega$. The base case is vacuously true. For the inductive hypothesis, suppose that $P(k) \Rightarrow Q(k)$. We wish to show that $P(k^+) \Rightarrow Q(k^+)$. Suppose that $\text{card }I = k^+$. Then there exists a bijection $f$ from $I$ onto $k^+$. Consider the set $A \subseteq I$ where $A = f^{-1}[\![k]\!]$. Clearly, $\text{card }A = k$, and by the inductive hypothesis, there exists a function $g$ with domain $A$ and with the property that for each $i \in A$, $g(i) \in H(i)$. Now consider the set $B \subseteq I$ where $B = f^{-1}[\![k^+ - \{0\}]\!]$. Similarly, $\text{card }B = k$, and the inductive hypothesis suggests the existence of a function $h$ such that $\text{dom }h = B$ and $h(i) \in H(i)$ for all $i \in B$. With these two functions at our disposal, we can now construct a third function $F = g \cup (h \upharpoonright \{f^{-1}(k)\})$ such that $\text{dom}F = I$ and $F(i) = H(i)$ for all $i$ in $I$, satisfying $Q(k^+)$. Hence, $S$ is inductive, and coincides with $\omega$.

*Note that $h \upharpoonright \{f^{-1}(k)\}$ denotes the ordered pair $\langle f^{-1}(k), h(f^{-1}(k)) \rangle$*

Comment: Your title is the dual statement to the one in your question. Your title asks about the product of finite sets, which need not be non-empty without the axiom of choice; your *actual question* is about the product of *finitely many* sets, which is indeed non-empty without the axiom of choice.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll fix my title. Thanks for bringing it up to my attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct apart from one error in the definition of $F$: You meant to write $f^{-1}(k)$ instead of $f^{-1}(k^+)$.

The second application of the induction hypothesis seems unnecessary. You can just write $i_0$ for the element of $I\backslash A$, choose an element $x$ of $H_{i_0}$ and define $F=g\cup\{(i_0,x)\}$.

**Style Critique:** You focus a bit too much on technicalities, which sometimes makes it hard to quickly grasp the idea behind an argument. In particular, it is much better to use the language of natural numbers instead of ordinals, i.e. you should not use the "fact" that natural numbers are elements and subsets of each other, but simply consider them as elements of an ordered set. This also makes notations like $f^{-1}(k)$ (where $k$ could be interpreted as an element or a subset) less ambiguous.

Comment: Actually, I think you're seeing something that I probably missed. I wrote $f^{-1}(k^+)$ because I thought that $g$ would account for the elements in $I$ corresponding up till $k^+$, and that the final choice from $k^+$ would be chosen from $h$. But I might be jumbling things up again. Conciseness and simplicity is something I struggle with :/

Comment: Also, I mentioned this with @Henno Brandsma's post, but why am I allowed to choose an arbitrary element in $H_{i_0}$?

Comment: Isn't that invoking the axiom of choice? What am I missing?

Comment: @mijucik: Henno already answered the second question. For the first: There is no element corresponding to $k^+$ because $k^+$ is not an element of $k^+$. The greatest element of $k^+$ is $k$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Makes sense. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no ensurance that the function you get on $A$ will coincide with that on $B$ on $A \cap B$, so in general you will not be able to combine them.

Just take the function on $A$ and extend it by a *single chosen pair* (no AC needed) to extend it to $I$.

All you need is that if $|I|=n+1$ then $|I\setminus \{i_0\}|=n$ for any $i_0 \in I$ and then we add a choice for $i_0$ from the non-empty $H(i_0)$  to be done. You add the one pair $(i_0, y)$ to the function defined on $I$ etc.

Don't overcomplicate things. You don't need the set $S$ either. Just induct on $P(n)$ as the statement

> There exists a choice function for a non-empty family of non-empty sets $\{H(i), i \in I\}$ whenever $|I|=n$.

just as the hint said. The showing a set to be inductive etc. need not be done *every time* you do an induction proof, it's part of the original proof that induction as a principle of proof is valid. After that you just show $\forall n: P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ directly (and $P(0)$ too).

Comment: So it's ok to choose an arbitrary pair from a set and add it? That was the problem I wasn't sure about. I made this very complicated because I thought I had to find a way to invoke that idea of "choosing" without explicitly doing so.

Comment: When is it the axiom of choice, and when is it not? I'm a little confused I think.

Comment: @mijucik choosing one element from a non-empty set is always allowed. But choosing infinitely many at the same time to form a new set (a choice function, e.g.) is not possible (in general) without AC. This exercise shows that finitely many choices is also OK without AC. It's making infinitely many "random" choices (without a rule, say) that uses AC.

Comment: Oh I see! So finite choices are always fine then? Just wondering - which axiom allows that? I'm guessing it's the schema of specification?

Comment: @mijucik in this case no axiom scheme at all. I choose $y \in H(i_0)$ and then form $\{(i_0, y)\}$ (pairing) and do the union with the function on $I\setminus \{i_0\}$. Picking an element from a non-empty set is just logic, not a set theory axiom.

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense now. Since I'm self-studying, I get things confused easily. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

**Synopsis**

Taking advice from @Henno Brandsma and @Stefan, I have shortened and simplified my proof considerably. I think in my original proof, I was too held up on trying to "choose" an element without explicitly doing so because I had a misunderstanding of the axiom of choice (which now I know is only needed when one is choosing random elements from an infinite number of sets without an explicit rule). My new proof eliminates this paranoia.

**Proof Revision**

Let $P(n)$ be the condition that if $\text{card }I = n$ and that $H(i)$ is nonempty for each $i \in I$, then there exists a function $f$ with $\text{dom}f = I$ and with $f(i) \in H(i)$ for all $i \in I$. We will perform induction on $P(n)$. $P(0)$ holds vacuously. For the induction hypothesis, suppose $P(n)$ is true. Then if $|I| = n+1$, $|I - \{i_0\}| = n$ for any $i_0 \in I$. Consider the choice function $g$ on $I - \{i_0\}$ guaranteed by the induction hypothesis. Then the function $h = g \cup \langle i_0, y \rangle$ with $y \in H(i_0)$ defines a choice function satisfying $P(n^+)$. So $P(n)$ holds for all $n \in \omega$.